# Why 1024 bits in randomness result in 140 HEX pairs?

Tags: x509certificate, x509

I am looking into the public key certificate of google.com, accessing it via chrome by going to https://google.com and clicking on the cert icon. I see that it says Public Key RSA (1024bits), but I see 140 HEX pairs in the actual key. Shouldn't I be seeing 128 HEX pairs instead? What goes underneath the conversion?

Answer (score 2):

You can lookup the structure in which a public RSA key is stored in [section 2.3.1 of RFC 3279](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3279#section-2.3.1):

```
The RSA public key MUST be encoded using the ASN.1 type RSAPublicKey:

  RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
     modulus            INTEGER,    -- n
     publicExponent     INTEGER  }  -- e

where modulus is the modulus n, and publicExponent is the public
exponent e.  The DER encoded RSAPublicKey is the value of the BIT
STRING subjectPublicKey.
```

In the case of your Google certificate you have found these 140 bytes:

```
30 81 89 02 81 81 00 d2 e6 cd 45 3e a2 44 0c 31 72 ef 2c 3b
e2 e5 c4 c6 a0 b8 32 0e 9c 7e 7b 68 2f 15 43 48 97 24 02 3c
2b c0 b8 cf 74 2b 76 37 33 e5 31 2f 72 53 f8 ac 5e 01 bb 7c
b7 32 40 e5 28 78 5f dd a9 3b da b6 af 05 30 57 2b c2 cb 59
29 2e 34 ec e5 89 9e 61 70 6a 91 ab 49 3c 1b 24 8e 12 35 82
42 6b fc 28 f2 ee ae 1b 5c 60 c5 e8 a5 3d a1 1a 3a 19 b3 5e
84 f9 b5 93 1d 05 e9 9d 2a ba 86 6b ce 7d 83 02 03 01 00 01
```

They looks like this if you look at them in an ASN.1 dump:

```
   <30 81 89>
271 30  137:           SEQUENCE {
   <02 81 81>
274 02  129:             INTEGER    
           :               00 D2 E6 CD 45 3E A2 44    ....E>.D
           :               0C 31 72 EF 2C 3B E2 E5    .1r.,;..
           :               C4 C6 A0 B8 32 0E 9C 7E    ....2..~
           :               7B 68 2F 15 43 48 97 24    {h/.CH.$
           :               02 3C 2B C0 B8 CF 74 2B    .<+...t+
           :               76 37 33 E5 31 2F 72 53    v73.1/rS
           :               F8 AC 5E 01 BB 7C B7 32    ..^..|.2
           :               40 E5 28 78 5F DD A9 3B    @.(x_..;
           :               DA B6 AF 05 30 57 2B C2    ....0W+.
           :               CB 59 29 2E 34 EC E5 89    .Y).4...
           :               9E 61 70 6A 91 AB 49 3C    .apj..I<
           :               1B 24 8E 12 35 82 42 6B    .$..5.Bk
           :               FC 28 F2 EE AE 1B 5C 60    .(....\`
           :               C5 E8 A5 3D A1 1A 3A 19    ...=..:.
           :               B3 5E 84 F9 B5 93 1D 05    .^......
           :               E9 9D 2A BA 86 6B CE 7D    ..*..k.}
           :               83                         .
   <02 03>
406 02    3:             INTEGER 65537
           :             }
```

The big block contains the 1024 bit modulus you were asking for. It is 1 byte longer (129 bytes) than strictly required for those 1024 bits because it is a positive number stored as a signed integer here; as the highest of the 1024 bits is set, the integer would be interpreted as a negative number if no leading byte `00` would have been prepended.

After this you see the public exponent 65537, requiring 3 bytes.

In addition to these 132 bytes of data, there are 8 bytes of encoding data:

- `<30 81 89>` : A SEQUENCE content 137 bytes long follows this marker
- `<02 81 81>` : An INTEGER content 129 bytes long follows this marker
- `<02 03>` : An INTEGER content 3 bytes long follows this marker